I don't belong in this list!
What should replace the question mark for this puzzle (and the title) to make sense? The answer is seven letters long.

          Eight
          Bean
          Season
          December
          Easy
          Effort 
          Genius 
          House
          Eyes
          Jay
          Kayla
          Elderly
          Emmanuel
          Engage
          Opponent
          President
          Curious
          Arthur
          Esther 
          Taylor
          Youth
          Vienna
          White
          Extraordinary
          While
            ?


I added the knowledge tag because I don’t think it is fair otherwise on people not from that country…

@PDT Yeah no prob, I didn't want to add the knowledge-tag, instead I wanted to write a comment that knowledge would be needed for the last step, but it was solved so fast so didn't have a chance to write the comment.

That is where I personally got lost because I thought the word was something commonly known due to the absence of the tag… but yeah it’s funny that happened!

The answer is

 Zachary.

Why? Most items on this list follow a very specific pattern:

 The beginnings of the words, when sounded out, spell out the letters of the alphabet!

So for example,

 "Eight" starts with the "A" sound ("ay"), "Bean" with "B" ("bee"), "Season" with "C" ("see"), and so on.

The only exceptions are:

 HOUSE, PRESIDENT, TAYLOR, WHITE which simply start with the corresponding letters of the alphabet, but not phonetically.

Thus the blank spot must go to

 A president previously in the White House with the name Taylor. Conveniently, Zachary Taylor fits the bill. This starts with Z but not the phonetic sound of the letter ("zee" or "zed") as we would expect from the last exceptional element of the list.

The title makes sense,

 since the answer is found by looking at the words that do not fit the rest of the list.


NIce job, that was very quick! :D

@Prim3numbah thanks for the neat puzzle, that was short and sweet :)

Glad you enjoyed :)
